# ifquery working but not ifdown or ifup

Tags: networking, interface

I am trying to configure my network card in Ubuntu 14.04.2 using the `/etc/network/interfaces` file.

The `ifquery` command works like a charm, always returns the right thing, but `ifdown` and `ifup` do not work until I reboot my computer and when they do, they still show error messages. I think that it might be because my file doesn't save or reload properly.

Here is what it looks like:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 10.0.0.119
netmask 255.0.0.0
gateway 10.0.0.1
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8
```

If there is any information I could add please ask and I will provide as soon as I can.

Comment: Whats the exact error message you are getting ?

Comment: ifdown: interface eth0 not configured

Comment: Whats the output of `ip a` ?

Comment: `eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:27:0e:37:8f:19 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.0.0.119/8 brd 10.255.255.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::227:eff:fe37:8f19/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever` @heemayl

Comment: What does `sudo ifup -v eth0` do ?

Comment: `Configuring interface eth0=eth0 (inet)
run-parts --verbose /etc/network/if-pre-up.d
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/ethtool
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/wireless-tools
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/wpasupplicant
ip addr add 10.0.0.101/255.0.0.0 broadcast 10.255.255.255       dev eth0 label eth0
RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Failed to bring up eth0.` @heemayl

Comment: From the `ip a` output it seems the device is already configured..can you confirm ? also if failed run `ip addr flush dev eth0` and then `sudo ifup -v eth0` ..then check..

Comment: Yes the device was already configured, and the two other commands worked, is that what the problem was? what was I not doing right? @heemayl

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems the interface `eth0` was configured before and the address was kept persistently (for some reason) by the kernel.

To clear all addresses from interface `eth0` without having to restart network services or bringing the interface up/down :

```
sudo ip addr flush dev eth0
```

Then you can use `ifup` to configure `eth0` by reading `/etc/network/interface` file :

```
sudo ifup eth0
```

For verbosity :

```
sudo ifup -v eth0
```